# Shell copy print without need to scroll up

Tags: shell, copy-paste, scroll-wheel

You know when you do a command on terminal, and it print many lines, and you want to copy-paste some lines to use.

So, the proceed is:

> 1- do the command on terminal
>       2- scroll-up till you find the line you want
>       3- you're a smart guy, so you double click the line to select it, than
>       4- middle-click to print the line on the command line (that is there, in the end of the window)

Now, you already printed one line. But you want another, so what you think to do is:

```
 1- press space-bar
 2- double-click the second line you want, and middle-click
```

But you can't do this, because when you PRESS that space-bar, the window scroll-down all the way till the command line, MAKING YOU need to scroll-up again till you find the line you want.

So, I want to know how can I improove this process? Without needing to scroll-up all the time I copy and print a line that way.

Or, another way to do this faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Edit` | `Profile Preferences` | `Scrolling` | `Scroll on keystroke`

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

1. Use `command | grep wanted` or `command | grep -v unwanted` (or combine them) to filter your command output
2. Open another terminal and paste the lines you need in this one (I have set an alias 'a' to run a new terminal in background, so my new terminal will have the same PWD if I run 'a' in the first terminal, afterwards I can run `command` in one of both and use the output in the "unused" terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to open two terminals and copy from one and paste to the other. Or use multiple tabs in terminals that have them. Or split windows in `screen`.